# Query about designing relationships in Sql Server's management studio interface

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Imagine I have two tables: Manager, Player.This is for a football team, where several players can play for one manager only and a manager manages several (11) players.

When designing the relationship in Sql Server, at the time the popup window comes up with the properties for the relationship, does it matter which side the tables are?

So in other words is there a difference in connecting the key from Player to Manager or from Manager to Player?

And how do I specify the relationship as 1:n or is it automatically decided as 1:n or 1:1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You connect `Player` to `Manager`, which will create a `FOREIGN KEY Player (manager_id) REFERENCES Manager (id)`

A relationship will be `1:n` unless there there is a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on `manager_id` in `Player` table, which is not your case.

As a rule, `1:1` relationships are stored in one table.

Comment: So I assume the table to be 1: will be the Primary Key table, which I connect from, right?

Comment: 1 manager (to which is the reference) can have N players (from which is the reference)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference.
The player needs to have a foreign key constraint that references the primary key (or another unique key) of the manager.

- source table: foreign key constraint
- target table: primary/unique key constraint

The primary key constraint needs to be in place before you can create a foreign key (constraint). It is automatically 1:n (or 0:n if your foreign key is nullable, i.e. there are players without a manager).

Comment: So to design a 1:1 relationship, do I add a constraint to simply say a manager cannot belong to two players?

Comment: See the comment to the other answer. You have a 0:n or 1:n situation, not 1:1. A manager can have zero/one or more players. 1:1 would be if a manager has 1 and only 1 player, which is very rare and you would just store that player in the manager table entirey.